# Load Spring integration context and access prototype bean from a Tasklet

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

Given the following spring integration configuration

```
...
import org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpRemoteFileTemplate;

@Configuration
public class FtpConfig {

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public FtpRemoteFileTemplate template(String param) {
        
        DefaultFtpSessionFactory sf = new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
        
        // these parameters can be determined at runtime, that's why I need param
        sf.setHost("some host");
        sf.setUsername("some user");
        sf.setPassword("some pass");
        sf.setPort(21);
        
        return new FtpRemoteFileTemplate(sf);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(FtpConfig.class);
        
        FtpRemoteFileTemplate template = ctx.getBean(FtpRemoteFileTemplate.class, "somevalue");

        String port = template.getSession().getHostPort();
        System.out.println(port);
        
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

I can bootstrap the application context and get the `FtpRemoteFileTemplate` bean by type and passing it a runtime parameter `"somevalue"`.
I want to be able to load this configuration in a Spring Batch Job which I am running using the `CommandLineJobRunner` utility:

```
java org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner mypackage.JobConfig jobname param=somevalue
```

This is my job configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class JobConfig {
    
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    
    @Bean
    public Job jobname() {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("jobname")
                    .start(downloadCsvFile())
                    .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step downloadCsvFile() {
        return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("downLoadFile")
                    .tasklet(ftpGetTasklet())
                    .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public FtpGetTasklet ftpGetTasklet() {
        return new FtpGetTasklet();
    }   
}
```

My question is how do I load and access the `FtpRemoteFileTemplate` bean from the `FtpGetTasklet`?

```
public class FtpGetTasklet implements Tasklet {

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        
        String param = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobParameters().getString("param");
        System.out.println("FtpGetTasklet execute: " + param);
        
        // how to load and access the template as I do in FtpConfig's main method???
        //
        // AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(FtpConfig.class);
        // FtpRemoteFileTemplate template = ctx.getBean(FtpRemoteFileTemplate.class, param);

        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what is your whole application is, but I would do like this:

```
@Configuration
@Import(FtpConfig.class)
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class JobConfig {
```

---

```
public class FtpGetTasklet implements Tasklet {

     @Autowired
     BeanFactory beanFactory;

    ...
      public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
         FtpRemoteFileTemplate template =  this.beanFactory.getBean(FtpRemoteFileTemplate.class, param);
 }
```

Comment: yes, I could have imported the configuration letting this way `CommandLineJobRunner` import the bean definitions, or put the integration config inside `JobConfig`

Comment: For completeness, the application at this stage is just using the ftp integration in a spring batch job by creating the template with runtime parameters.